# Missing "place order" button at step 5 after upgrade to Magento 1.9.1.0

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, upgrade, ce-1.9.1.0

After upgrading my store from 1.5.0.1 to 1.9.1.0 the checkout won't work correct anymore. After some Google queries I found out that I need to change the checkout file payment.phtml which can be found in /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml.

I have changed:

```
<fieldset>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') ?>
</fieldset>
```

To:

```
<fieldset id="checkout-payment-method-load">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') ?>
</fieldset>
```

This worked perfectly to get through the steps.
But in step 5, the order review page, the "Place Order" button is missing.

Does someone have a suggestion? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've found the problem myself. I've removed the checkout.xml in /app/design/frontend/default/MY_THEME/layout/checkout.xml in order to use the version which comes with the base files.

Comment: You will want to go through all your theme files and remove anything that isn't needs (Or anything that has been updated for 1.9)